# How to handle different return codes in apache airflow?

Tags: airflow

we want run some batches with airflow. Some of batches have return code like 0 - success and 1-4 suceess with warning and above 5 failed. Should i write custom code to handle it?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this? How has it failed or been lacking?

Comment: Currently i am using bash operator to run the job. So checked that code for bash operator it says returncode != 0 raise airlflowExecption. I can modify this work . But i dont want to do it  here because i want handle different batches with different kind of rules like job1 its ok fail at ret code 4 and job2 its not. I want to know if there any airflow code that handles to it

Comment: It's not standard to use anything but 0 to indicate success. Every other exit code indicates a failure of some sort. Airflow operates on this principle so you're going to have to write a custom operator to handle whatever it is you're trying to do. I would strongly suggest not misusing exit codes and figure out a different way to do what you want to do.